# How to execute a function at same time for multiple people?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, logic

I have an application stored in IBM server where the same application is being used by multiple people. We have a feature where we need to execute that particular piece of code exactly at same time for multiple people. How can I achieve this? The feature is that, a particular person will initiate a recording feature which will open the microphones of every person. This is achieved by maintaining a variable whose value I am setting and de setting, but when I am ending the recording the person who ends immediately the code gets executed but for other people it takes few milliseconds and even seconds to execute that same piece of code? Any help how can I tackle to this issue.

```
render () {
this.props.meetingData.isMeetingDiscussionStarted ? this.recordFullAudio() : null;
!this.props.meetingData.isMeetingDiscussionStarted ? this.stopRecordingAudio() : null;
}


recordFullAudio = () => {
    const constraints = {
      audio: {
        channels: 1
      },
      video: false
    };
    getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(stream => {
        this.stream = stream;
        const mimeType = 'audio/mpeg';
        const mime = ['audio/wav', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/webm', 'audio/ogg']
          .filter(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported)[0];
        const options = {
          mimeType: 'audio/webm',
        };
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
          audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {                         });
      }).catch(error => { });
  }


stopRecordingAudio = () => {
    if (this.mediaRecorder && this.mediaRecorder.state !== 'inactive') {
      this.mediaRecorder.stop();
      this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
      });
    }
    // Cleanup
    this.mediaRecorder = null;
    this.stream = null;
  }
```

`isMeetingDiscussionStarted` is that variable maintained in NodeJS sharedb doc which is used to start and end recording.

Comment: What approach do you use now? Why it can take even seconds? Can you show some code? Doing something "immediately" is basically impossible, there will always be at least some network latency.

Comment: Since it's a production level code and has integration with NodeJS so there will be lot code to post here. In short, I have a variable stored in my DOC data which is managed by NodeJS and I have connected my Node to React with websockets. That variable value I have put inside my render() function and based on that value the function will get executed.

Comment: If your using webSockets, that should be milliseconds.  Are you not just broadcasting a stop message?.  Your not retrieving the status using a DB are you, that could add a fair bit of latency, just send the stop message as part of your websocket message.

Comment: I am just fetching that variable value from the DOC data in my ReactJS. The lag is variable sometimes it takes 2 seconds more, and sometimes 1 second. So for every person attending that meeting, the ending time is different for everyone which is I don't know because at the end I want to mix all those audios and hence it is creating en echo effect.